# MYSQL QUERY multiple tables count

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am having problems building a query which delimit the number of lawyers by branch of law in one particular territory(province) of the country.

I have four tables, one with the branchlaws, one for users, one where lawyers add branches where the practice law and one for territories.

I am able to summarize all this information with the following query:

```
 $lawyersbyprovince = DB::table('branchlawsubareas')
 ->leftJoin('lawyerbranches', function($join) {
     $join->on( 'branchlawsubareas.id', '=', 'lawyerbranches.subarea_id');
 })
 ->leftJoin('users', function($join) {
     $join->on( 'lawyerbranches.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
 })
 ->leftJoin('states', function($join) {
     $join->on('users.working_province', '=', 'states.id_state');
 })
 ->leftJoin('branchlaws', 'branchlawsubareas.area_id', '=', 'branchlaws.id')
 ->select('branchlawsubareas.name as subarea',
     DB::raw('count(lawyerbranches.subarea_id) as total'),
     'branchlawsubareas.id' 
 )
 ->where('states.id_state','=', $province)
 ->groupBy('branchlawsubareas.id')
 ->get();
```

This query returns the number of lawyers per branch of law but it does not delimit by province. I have spent enough time trying things but obviously I missing something.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to join instead the states of leftjoin.

```
$lawyersbyprovince = DB::table('branchlawsubareas')
->leftJoin('lawyerbranches', 'branchlawsubareas.id', '=', 'lawyerbranches.subarea_id')
->leftJoin('users', 'lawyerbranches.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('branchlaws', 'branchlawsubareas.area_id', '=', 'branchlaws.id')
->join('states', 'users.working_province', '=', 'states.id_state')
->where('states.id_state','=', $province)
->select('branchlawsubareas.name as subarea',
    DB::raw('count(lawyerbranches.subarea_id) as total'),
   'branchlawsubareas.id' 
)
->groupBy('branchlawsubareas.id')
->get();
```

Now if this does not work, you have another way. Remove `where()` clause and change your select like this

```
...
->select(''branchlawsubareas.id', 'states.id as state_id')
...
```

This will return a collection with ALL the data. Then you can manipulate that collection like this

```
$newCollection = $resultFromQuery->where('state_id', $province);
$newCollection->count(); //number of laywer in that state
```

I hope this helps, or simply gives you a hint.

Comment: Thanks finally what I did was two queries. Compare those two with diffKeys and manipulate the new collection to obtain the desired result but this approach is not effficient. I will leave the question open until someone can find a proper answer because the solution found until now is quite inefficient.

Comment: Can you add a diagram (image) of your tables in your original question. It's easier when visualizing the tables.